# tikz: Label number of edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, loops, edge

In the following picture there are multiple edges between two vertices. But I am able to draw single edge. So I want to label the number of edges. How can I do it? For example there are `$3$` edges between `$1$` and `$4$`. How can I label `$3$`?

```
\[\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, every loop/.style={}]

    \vertex[fill] (1) at (.5, 1)  [label=above: 1] {}; 
 \vertex [fill](2) at (0,.5) [label=left: 2] {};
\vertex[fill] (3) at (.5,0) [label=above: 3]{};
  \vertex[fill] (4) at (1,0) [label=above: 4] {};   
    \vertex[fill] (5) at (1.5, 0.5) [label=right: 5]  {};  
    \vertex [fill](6) at (1,1) [label=left: 6] {};  
 \draw (1,1)  to[in=-50,out=-130,loop] (1,1);
    \path


        (1) edge (4)
        (1) edge (4)
        (1) edge (4)
        (1) edge (2)
        (2) edge (4)
        (2) edge (5)
        (3) edge (5)
        (3) edge (6)

     ;  
\end{tikzpicture}\]
```

Comment: `(1) edge node [above] {label} (4)`, or with use `quotes` library and `(1) edge ["label"] (4)`. if you will extend your code sniped to complete compilable document, we can simply show this on your picture example. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Thank you very much. But  when I label all edges the numbers are not understandable for which edge it is defined.  I mean it is not understandable that for which edges the labelling is done. @Zarko

Comment: well, this is not latex problem :-). please consider my ask and extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with  `\documentclass` and ending with  `\end{document}` which we can test and than make suggestion how to place your edge labels.

Comment: `(2) edge["e"{swap,pos=.2}] (4)` for example will move the node to the other side of the line (`swap` does that) and to 20% along the line from `2` to `4`, instead of halfway (`pos=0.2` does that).   (By the way, @Zarko how is the positioning of the edge labels not a latex problem?)

Comment: @TorbjørnT., how to write edges' labels are LaTeX problem and I give him a suggestion how to write them ... however,  how are vertex placing and edges  labels overlaps is image design problem.  since I can't test his code and see how it looking, I can't help him further. So I ask him for MWE. and this ask is not LaTeX problem.

Answer (score 2):

probably you looking for the following:

[image]

since you not provide complete small document, which gives information what is `\vertex`, i reconstruct own code, for which i hope that is similar to what you like to have. in this I made to important changes:

- remove `scale` and accordingly multiply each coordinate
- reduce font size for edge labels
- define positions for labels so, that they not overlap

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                  quotes}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
  vertex/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt},
  every edge quotes/.style = {auto=left, sloped, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt}
                          ]
  \node[vertex] (1) at (1.5,3)     [label=above: 1] {};
  \node[vertex] (2) at (0,1.5)     [label=left: 2]  {};
  \node[vertex] (3) at (1.5,0)     [label=left: 3]  {};
  \node[vertex] (4) at (3,0)       [label=right: 4] {};
  \node[vertex] (5) at (4.5,1.5)   [label=right: 5] {};
  \node[vertex] (6) at (3,3)       [label=above: 6] {};
  %
  \path   (1) edge [pos=.35, "a"] (4)
          (1) edge ["b"]  (2)
          (2) edge ["c"]  (4)
          (2) edge [pos=.35, "d"]  (5)
          (3) edge [in=-50,out=-130, looseness=12] (3)
          (3) edge ["e"]  (5)
          (3) edge [pos=.75, "f"]  (6);
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

**addendum:**
an alternative code, slightly shorter, using the `positioning` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 11mm and 11mm,
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt,
                 label=#1, node contents={}},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=left, sloped, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\node (1) [dot=above:1];
\node (2) [dot= left:2, below  left=of 1];
\node (3) [dot= left:3, below right=of 2];
\node (4) [dot=right:4,       right=of 3];
\node (5) [dot=right:5, above right=of 4];
\node (6) [dot=above:6, above  left=of 5];
%
\path   (1) edge [pos=.35, "a"] (4)
        (1) edge ["b"]  (2)
        (2) edge ["c"]  (4)
        (2) edge [pos=.35, "d"]  (5)
        (3) edge [in=-50,out=-130, looseness=12] (3)
        (3) edge ["e"]  (5)
        (3) edge [pos=.75, "f"]  (6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```